# how i insert a key into a js array to convert to json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following flat array

```js
let data = [
    ["0000001", "SCHOLL", "S", "CEDULA", "NOESTUDIANTE", "GRADO"],
    ["0000002", "MOVIL", "S", "CELULAR", ""],
    ["0000003", "ECHALE", "S", "CONTRATO", "NOCLIENTE", ""],
];
```

And I have the following function, But this function returns me an array within another array of references, so I would like to be able to assign keys to the values ​​that come flat, I have tried everything, but I don't know very well how to do it, if you could help me please and grateful for your comments

```js
function infoTransform(values) {
    return values.map((value) => {
        let [service, name, ...references] = value;
        service = parseInt([value[0]]);
        references = references.filter((reference) => reference !== "");
        references = references.splice(1);
        let Myjson = JSON.stringify(references);
        return {
            service,
            name,
            Myjson,
        };
    });
}
console.log(infoTransform(data));
```

I wish it would return something like this to me

```js
let data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "SCHOLL",
        REF1: "CEDULA",
        REF2: "NOESTUDIANTE",
        REF3: "GRADO",
    },
    { id: 2, name: "MOBILE", REF1: "CEDULA" },
    { id: 3, name: "EPALEE", REF1: "NOFOOD", REF2: "FOOBAR" },
];
```

Comment: how `MOVIL` became `MOBILE` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let data = [
    ["0000001", "SCHOLL", "S", "CEDULA", "NOESTUDIANTE", "GRADO"],
    ["0000002", "MOVIL", "S", "CELULAR", ""],
    ["0000003", "ECHALE", "S", "CONTRATO", "NOCLIENTE", ""],
];

function infoTransform(values) {
    return values.map(([id, name, _, ...refs]) => ({
        id: parseInt(id),
        name,
        ...Object.fromEntries(
            refs.filter(r => r !== "")
                .map((r, i) => [`REF${i + 1}`, r])
        )
    }))
}

console.log(infoTransform(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function should be something like this:

```
function infoTransform(values) {
  return values.map((value) => {
    let [service, name, ...references] = value;
    service = parseInt([value[0]]);
    references = references.filter((reference) => reference !== '');
    references = references.splice(1);
    let Myjson = references.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
      acc[`REF${index + 1}`] = curr;
      return acc;
    }, {});
    return {
      service,
      name,
      ...Myjson,
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [
  ["0000001", "SCHOLL", "S", "CEDULA", "NOESTUDIANTE", "GRADO"],
  ["0000002", "MOVIL", "S", "CELULAR", ""],
  ["0000003", "ECHALE", "S", "CONTRATO", "NOCLIENTE", ""]
];

function infoTransform(values) {
  return data.map(el => {
      let id = parseInt(el[0], 10);
      let obj = {id: id, name: el[1]};

      for (let i=3; i<el.length; i++) {
          if (el[i].length)
              obj["REF" + (i-2)] = el[i];
      };
      return obj;

  });
}

console.log(infoTransform(data));
```

Comment: ID is not a number but a string with all the zeroes replaced

Comment: @Rubydesic - Thanks, I didn't mentioned it. I changed the code for it.

Comment: regex is unnecessary

Comment: @Rubydesic - Again right. I thought leading zeros would make for `parseInt` problems, especially in interpreting as octals.

Comment: that is true, if that is the worry, then I suggest you include a radix: parseInt(el[0], 10)

Answer (score 1):

In a parralel time I do that...
.. with Destructuring assignment

```js
const data = 
      [ [ "0000001", "SCHOLL", "S", "CEDULA", "NOESTUDIANTE", "GRADO"] 
      , [ "0000002", "MOVIL", "S", "CELULAR", ""] 
      , [ "0000003", "ECHALE", "S", "CONTRATO", "NOCLIENTE", ""]
      ] 

const infoTransform = arr => arr.map(([id,name,_,...refs])=>
        ({ id:+id, name, ...refs.filter(x=>!!x)
                                    .reduce((a,c,i)=>
                                      { a[`REF${i+1}`]=c; return a }
                                      ,{})}))


console.log( infoTransform(data) )
```